# How to change path to boost 1.61.0

Tags: ubuntu, boost

Im install boost 1.61.0 from tar.gz and my boost is located /home/user/boost but I need change the path to /usr/include/boost how to change path ?

Comment: cd /usr/include/boost

Comment: no go to path, change path I solve the problem
http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/wily/universe/l/libboost1.58-all-dev/install/index.html